# Tab is not showing in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Hello I am noob in Android.

I am using `appcompat` support library to add tabs in `ActionBarActivity`. I have written the code to add but tabs is not showing see it in the screenshot. I could not catch the problem.

Any idea why it so ?

```
private ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // find the action bar
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // First Tab of the Activity
    ActionBar.Tab mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("First Tab").setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);
    mActionBar.selectTab(mTab);

    // Second Tab of the Activity
    mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("Second Tab").setTabListener(this);
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction) {
    if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.container, new FirstFragment());
    } else {
        fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment());
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: did you add the tablistener?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar See in the question `ActionBar.Tab mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText("First Tab").setTabListener(this);
`

Comment: please look my answer below it is working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add setNavigationMode like this:

```
  actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Comment: +1 This solved my problem `actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Comment: I am happy to solve your problem maybe you can upvoted asnwer :)